# Spring Security: Check whether URL is allowed for User via Java code

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, logout

The case is: after logout the user has to be redirected to the page he was. But in case if the page cannot be accessed by anonymous (because of spring security intercept-url config), the user has to be redirected to another specific URL (e.g. homepage).

I can get the redirectUrl in LogoutSuccessHandler. After this I want to check whether this URL can be accessed by anonymous user. If not - redirect user to homepage.

So the question is: **how can I check via java whether the specific URL can be accessed by anonymous user?**